# IsCancellationRequested is always false

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, .net-core

I am calling same function in parallel using Task.Whenall().I And am trying to add functionality to stop execution using CancellationTokenSource .
CancellationTokenSource return true when I call Token.Cancel() but afterwards it changes to false and therefore token.IsCancellationRequested is always false.

```html
    CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Runcase(List<string> products,string runnumber,string button)
            {
              var token = _tokenSource.Token;
                try
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        var productinfo = products;
                        List<string> productids = new List<string>(productinfo);
                        var runnum = runnumber;
                        string runid = "";
                        int count = productids.Count();
                        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                        int rawid = 0;
                         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                            {
                               tasks.Add(RunServiceAsync(productids[i], runnum,rawid,token));
                            }
                        
                        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                        ViewBag.completed = "Success";
                        return View();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.productinfo = new MultiSelectList(_context.inputValuesConfigurations, "ProductID", "ProductName");
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please enter a valid data...");
                        return View();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
```

When I call this function ,token return true

```html
 public void Stopexecution()
        {
            _tokenSource.Cancel();
        }
```

But in below code it is always false

```html
public async Task RunServiceAsync(string productids,string runnumber,int rawid,CancellationToken token)
        {
            using(var dbscope = _service.CreateScope())
            {
                var dbcontext = dbscope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
                var productid = Convert.ToInt32(productids);
                var inputvals = dbcontext.inputValuesConfigurations.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ProductID == productid);
                var run = runnumber + '_' + inputvals.ProductID;
                int count = 0;
                bool completion1 = false; // for j
                int totalCount = CountProductvalues(inputvals);
                while (!completion1) // 
                {
                    var errorrun = dbcontext.errorlogs.Select(m => m.ProductID == productid).ToList().Count();
                    totalCount = completion == true ? errorrun : totalCount;
                    for (int j = rawid; j < totalCount; j++)
                    {
                        if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        }
                        if(!completion) // Stop if First run complete
                        {
                            Inputvalues c1 = new Inputvalues(j, inputvals);
                            InputValuesViewmodel inputValues = new InputValuesViewmodel()
                            {
                                ProductID = productid,
                                STATE = c1.State,
                                AGE1 = c1.AGE1,
                                SEX1 = c1.SEX1,
                                UND_CLASS1 = c1.UND_CLASS1,
                                FACE_OPTIONS = 1,
                                FACE_SCHEDULE = "1ü" + c1.SOLVE_TARGET_YEAR + "0ü" + c1.FACE_SCHEDULE,
                                PREM_OPTIONS = premoption,
                                PAY_PREM_TARGET_ID = c1.PAY_PREM_TARGET_ID,
                                PAY_PREM_TARGET_YEAR = c1.PAY_PREM_TARGET_YEAR,
                                SOLVE_TARGET_ID = 1,
                                SOLVE_TARGET_YEAR = c1.SOLVE_TARGET_YEAR
                            };
                            await RecieveResponseasync(inputValues, run, j,productid);
                            
                            //completion = j == totalCount ? true : false;
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        }
```

Calling `Stopexecution()`

```html
$("#btnstop").click(function (e) {
                    
                    $("#btnstart span").text("Rerun");
                    let btnstartval = $("#btnstart").val('Rerun');
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Url.Action("Stopexecution", "CallService")",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: Where are you calling `StopExecution()`?

Comment: Please show where you grab a token from _tokenSource and pass that to the method.

Comment: I just updated my code. Can you please take a look at it again? Thanks

Comment: @insane_developer I am calling StopExecution() from the view using ajax call.

Comment: @Neu that would be a different request. Not like I can run this thing now to check, but I don't think you would be using the same `CancellationToken` object.

Comment: @insane_developer can you please suggest how should I call StopExecution() so it can use same CancellationToken object.

Comment: @Neu one way, I think, would be making it static, but then you have to see whether that affects other calls that may be using the token. This is probably not a good approach, anyway, a controller with a static property. Why would you cancel the token, based on what?

Comment: @insane_developer So I am trying to cancel token when Stop button is clicked on the UI. so I can stop the running process. And what controller you are suggesting to make it as static?

Comment: @Andy can you please tell me how I can make Token source static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first issue here is that you have a `CancellationTokenSource` as a member of a controller. Controllers are transient, meaning they are created every time a request is made to it. So, you are creating a new token source every time that controller is called.

To fix this, you could make this static:

```
static CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Remember to reset that source every time a request is made... because once it's cancelled, it's cancelled for good. Also, then what happens if this endpoint gets called two or more times at the same time. You will have a race condition.

Second issue is: this isn't a very "Controller-like" pattern. You should re-think how you are generating data. If a call to an endpoint takes longer than 100 ms, then you are going to run in to thread/socket starvation issues if your service gets hot.

Comment: Thank you @Andy. This worked and I will take a look into the approach you recommended.

Comment: @Neu -- no problem... Hopefully you can sort that out so you don't need to cancel a pending request :) Good luck to you.